# Django - displaying values from a dictionary nested in a list in an html template

Tags: python, django

I have the followed class-based views in my views.py file:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'annual_means/home.html'

    site_list = AnnualMean.objects.values("site").distinct()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['sites'] = AnnualMean.objects.values("site").distinct()
        return context
```

At the top of my html template, just for testing this out, I have {{sites}} and it is displaying:

Below, I have the following html code:

```
{% for value in sites %}
    <li>{{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And it lists all the key:value pairs as shown above, e.g. {'site': 'Belfast Centre'}, instead of just the values. I assume this is due to the dictionary in the QuerySet being nested within a list. Is there a way I can return just the a dictionary or otherwise get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you  should use this as :

```
{% for value in sites %}
    <li>{{value.site}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It will now print the values in list

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! I thought I tried that but it might have just been site.value

Answer (score 0):

You can access a [key in a dictionary using the dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#variables):

> Dictionary lookup, attribute lookup and list-index lookups are implemented with a dot notation:
>
> ```
>    {{ my_dict.key }}
>    {{ my_object.attribute }}
>    {{ my_list.0 }}
> ```

For your code, that would be:

```
{% for value in sites %}
    <li>{{value.site}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```